# How do I finish this Rock, Paper, Scissors game in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random

userscore = 0
computerscore = 0

print("Welcome to the Rock, Paper, Scissors Game")
while True:
    print("User Score = ", userscore, " Computer Score = ", computerscore)
    print("Rock, Paper or Scissors?")

    userweapon = str(input())
    print("You chose ", userweapon)

    computerweapon = random.randint(1,3)

    if computerweapon == 1:
        computerweapon = "Rock"
    elif computerweapon == 2:
        computerweapon = "Paper"
    else:
        computerweapon = "Scissors"

    print("Computer chose ", computerweapon)

    if userweapon == computerweapon:
        print("You chose the same Weapon, it's a draw.")
    elif userweapon == "Rock" and computerweapon == "Paper":
        print("Computer Point.")
        computerscore +=1
    elif userweapon == "Rock" and computerweapon == "Scissors":
        print("User Point.")
        userscore +=1
    elif userweapon == "Paper" and computerweapon == "Rock":
        print("User Point.")
        userscore +=1
    elif userweapon == "Paper" and computerweapon == "Scissors":
        print("Computer Point.")
        computerscore +=1
    elif userweapon == "Scissors" and computerweapon == "Rock":
        print("Computer point.")
        computerscore +=1
    elif userweapon == "Scissors" and computerweapon == "Paper":
        print("User Point.")
```

How do I ask the User to type in how many points they want to pay upto and how do I use this information to end the game when input() has been reached?

I know this code looks pretty bad, but I'm a beginner, it's the best I can do. Thanks for reading I will vote for best answer.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
while True:
```

Try this (and this has no error checking of the input):

```
rounds = int(input('How many rounds do you want to play?'))
for i in range(rounds):
```

Comment: What does for i in range(var): mean? I see it quite a lot but I don't understand!

Comment: range(var) returns a list of items from 0 to var. for i in range iterates over that generated list, then discards the list.

Comment: in your interactive session try just typing `range(5)`. It prints out `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, in essence making a list for you (it's a bit more complicated than that, but it has that effect). The `for` loop assigns each element to i one after another until it's done. You can ignore i, or you could print it out to keep the user informed of which round they're playing.

Comment: Also when I put that into the code when it runs it doesn't +1 onto the score

Comment: Did you play `Scissors`? You forgot the `userscore += 1` on that condition

Comment: I added that in, but it still won't update score :/ any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is pseudo-code.

Prior to `userweapon = str(input())`, ask the user how many games they'd like to play.  Something like `usergames = int(input())`.  create a gamesplayed variable and put a `while True:`.  At the end of each loop, increment `gamesplayed = gamesplayed + 1`  It'll pop back up and check the while True status until it has played the required number of games.

Answer (score 0):

Have a go with this.

```
userscore = 0
computerscore = 0
winscore = 0 ## This will store the number of points we play to

print("Welcome to the Rock, Paper, Scissors Game")
print("How many points would you like to play to?")
winscore = int(input()) ## Takes input and casts it to an int. This will raise a ValueError if the user inputs anything other than a number.

while True:
    if userscore == winscore:
        print("You win!")
        break ## Break will stop loops(for, while) running, like return does in a function
    elif computerscore == winscore:
        print("You lost :(")
        break

    print("User Score = ", userscore, " Computer Score = ", computerscore)
    print("Rock, Paper or Scissors?")

    ## Weaponising and fighting go here ##
    ## ... ##
```

If you want, you could even move the entire loop into a [function](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/functions.html) using the `def` keyword, and then just call the function again after asking the player if they want to play again once you break out of the loop.
Oh, and it's all right to have slightly messy code to begin with. ;) We all had to start somewhere, and yours isn't even that bad. Keep up the good work and you'll be up there with the best in no time!

Answer (score 0):

Use a for or a while loop:

```
while a!=rounds:
    *your code*
```

or

```
for i in range (0, rounds):
    *your code*
    i=i+1
```